# WPF Expander Toggle Button - adress them in setter?

Tags: wpf, expander, setter, togglebutton, basedon

Hi is it possible to assign a ToggleButtonStyle in a Setter in the ExpanderStyle?
Like this is possible in the Calendar:

```
<Style x:Key="CS" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}" >
    <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CalendarDayButtonStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="CalendarButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CalendarButtonStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="CalendarItemStyle" Value="{StaticResource CalendarItemStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

Background of the question: In BasedOn-Styles i only change the setter and not the whole template for small changes.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible out-of-the-box. Probably because there isn't one `ToggleButton` Style, there is four, one for each `ExpandDirection`

- Down - **ExpanderDownHeaderStyle**
- Up - **ExpanderUpHeaderStyle**
- Left - **ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle**
- Right - **ExpanderRightHeaderStyle**

Probably overkill for you but if you really need this functionality to be reusable you could create your own custom control where you add four Dependency Properties, `ToggleButtonDownStyle`, `ToggleButtonUpStyle`, `ToggleButtonLeftStyle` and `ToggleButtonRightStyle` and copy the default style for `Expander` into the default Style for your custom control but change the StaticResource for `ToggleButton` Style to a `TemplateBinding`

So it doesn't come easy but this would allow you to do what you're after (and I'm guessing you're mostly interested in the default `Down` direction)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:StyleableExpander}">
    <Setter Property="ToggleButtonDownStyle" Value="{StaticResource toggleButtonDownStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToggleButtonUpStyle" Value="{StaticResource toggleButtonUpStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToggleButtonLeftStyle" Value="{StaticResource toggleButtonLeftStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToggleButtonRightStyle" Value="{StaticResource toggleButtonRightStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

---

Here is how to control could look, I named it `StyleableExpander` and put it in a "WPF Custom Control Library" for reusability. Only added `ToggleButtonDownStyle` for demo purpose

```
[StyleTypedProperty(Property="ToggleButtonDownStyle",
                    StyleTargetType=typeof(ToggleButton))]
public class StyleableExpander : Expander
{
    public static DependencyProperty ToggleButtonDownStyleProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ToggleButtonDownStyle",
                                    typeof(Style),
                                    typeof(StyleableExpander),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DefaultToggleButtonDownStyle));
    public Style ToggleButtonDownStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(ToggleButtonDownStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToggleButtonDownStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    static StyleableExpander()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(StyleableExpander),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(StyleableExpander)));
    }
    private static ResourceDictionary _resources;
    private static Style DefaultToggleButtonDownStyle
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resources == null)
            {
                Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/StyleableExpanderLibrary;component/Themes/Generic.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
                _resources = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
            }
            return _resources["ExpanderDownHeaderStyle"] as Style;
        }
    }
}
```

---

And here is (the very verbose) `Generic.xaml` with the default style. StaticResource for the `ToggleButton` has been changed to `{TemplateBinding ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}`. To get all four directions you would need to change the triggers for `ExpandDirection` as well

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StyleableExpanderLibrary">
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                            <TransformCollection>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                            </TransformCollection>
                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                            <TransformCollection>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                            </TransformCollection>
                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                            <TransformCollection>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                            </TransformCollection>
                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:StyleableExpander}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:StyleableExpander}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Style="{TemplateBinding ToggleButtonDownStyle}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The Expander control does not expose that property. However you can set the expander template and show that button in any way you want.

[Here is the complete XAML code for the default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296.aspx)

You should copy that template to your project and modify the ToggleButton to use any style you want:

```
<ToggleButton OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
    Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}"
    IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    Style="{StaticResource YourStyleHere}">
```